# Django ContentType Name of CamelCase models

Tags: python, django

I am playing with generic foreign key, and i wanted to filter the available models with `limit_choices_to`.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class FooBar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Treatment(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     limit_choices_to={'model': 'foo'})  # !!
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)  
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

So it works with the class `Foo`, in lower case, but for `FooBar` i tried `foo_bar`, `fooBar`, `foo bar` and none of these works... How am i suppose to spell it ??
I can see its separated by spaces in the drop down menu of the content type form.

Comment: I would guess "FooBar" or "foobar"

Answer (score 0):

Finally, its `foobar`. But the class name is displayed with spaces in the drop down menu if it had camel case.